# Chart.js calculates the width of my time x-axis wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I've got a time x-axis in my bar chart and a single value for the day `2017-10-09`.

I'd like the chart to have the width of 31 bars (for 31 days in this month), but as I've only got one value, chartjs calculates the width to 1 bar.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var data = JSON.parse('{"first":[{"x":"2017-10-09","y":107}]}');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,120,200,0.4)",
      data: data.first,
      label: 'First',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    hover: {
      mode: null
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        bounds: 'ticks',
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMM YY',
            day: 'D'
          },
          unit: 'month'
        },
        type: 'time'
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return (value % 1 === 0) ? value : null;
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wk65979s/3/).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please put all relevant code *within* the question. I've edited it for you here.

Comment: it's not that it calculates the width to one bar, it shows the bar in full width. 
if you add a few more dates, you'll see that the width of the x-axis doesn't change

Comment: @rebecca Uhm, yeah. If my data is `{"x":"2017-10-01","y":107}, {"x":"2017-10-15","y":107}, {"x":"2017-10-31","y":107}` it doesn't make it any better. I'd like that one can assume at a glance which days have values.

Comment: see my answer + examples please

Answer (score 0):

Like i mentioned in the comment: it's not that your x-axis has the wrong width, but the bar itself:
I added `barThickness: 10` to set the width of the bar and now it only shows on the specific day

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var data = JSON.parse('{"first":[{"x":"2017-10-09","y":107}]}');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,120,200,0.4)",
      data: data.first,
      label: 'First',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    hover: {
      mode: null
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        bounds: 'ticks',
        categoryPercentage: 1,
        barPercentage: .1,
        
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMM YY',
            day: 'D'
          },
          unit: 'month'
        },
        type: 'time'
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return (value % 1 === 0) ? value : null;
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

here's a snippet with more values:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var width = ctx.width/31;
var data = JSON.parse('{"first":[{"x":"2017-10-05","y":107},{"x":"2017-10-09","y":107},{"x":"2017-10-15","y":107},{"x":"2017-10-31","y":107}]}');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,120,200,0.4)",
      data: data.first,
      label: 'First',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    hover: {
      mode: null
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{

        bounds: 'ticks',
        barThickness: width,
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMM YY',
            day: 'D'
          },
          unit: 'month'
        },
        type: 'time'
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return (value % 1 === 0) ? value : null;
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: But that requires the x-axis to always have the width of 310px, right? My chart is resized with the browser window, so if the x-axis has a different width, the proportion is incorrect again.

Comment: well, not really..play around with it! it's not so clear to see, since we don't see the days on the x-axis, but you enabled 'responsive' so the bar's stay at their relevant x points. 
you can also declare something like a maxThickness for your bar

Comment: I don't get how this solves the problem with the proportion. The bar for a single day in a month with 31 days should always be 31/1 of the x-axis' width.

Comment: you asked about the width of the x-axis not the width of the bar, so be clearer with your question

Comment: _I'd like the chart to have the width of 31 bars..._ - For me it sounds like the proportion matters. Sorry if you got it wrong.

Comment: but it has the width of 31 days or rather the month. otherwise the bar on 15th oct wouldn't be in the middle of the chart ?

Comment: I didn't notice that you updated your code. Yes, at the moment of the chart initialisation it's correct. But once you resize the chart, you'll need to adjust the bar thickness. And often I got many values over months and years for a single chart. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/WzYuw) for an example, where the proportion is perfect. So width/31 isn't the way to go here. There must be a native way from chart.js..